# Using jq to create comma separated list fields in JSON array

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to use `jq` to join the values inside a JSON array into a single line comma separated list.  (Without trailing comma)

```
{
  "hardware": [
    "abc",
    "def",
    "ghi"
  ]
}
```

To create
"abc, def, ghi"

I can join values together using

```
jq -jr '(.hardware[])' input.json

abcdefghi
```

I have tried to insert comma and space but cannot work

```
jq -jr '(.hardware[]|join(", ")' 

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

(.hardware[]|join(", ")
```

Could someone point me to the correct syntax to use?

Thanks

Densha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for

```
jq -r '.hardware | join(", ")'
```

The syntax error from the version you posted is because the opening `(` doesn't have a matching `)`, but in any case `join` needs to be given all the values at once, so `.hardware` is better than `.hardware[]` (which will pass them through one at a time).

Answer (score 3):

Your `jq` expression contains unbalanced parentheses. The `join()` function also needs an array, not individual values (use `.hardware | join(", ")` rather than `.hardware[] | join(", ")`).

If you want properly formatted CSV output, you could use the expression `.hardware | @csv`:

```
$ jq -r '.hardware | @csv' file.json
"abc","def","ghi"
```